# Android Studio no me detecta una función dentro de una librería propia en Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, github

Estoy intentando crear una librería en Kotlin. He seguido varios tutoriales, pero en todos me quedo en el mismo punto.

La librería está creada (tan sólo tiene una función, hello(), y tan sólo suma dos números que se le insertan cómo argumentos). En el proyecto dónde quiero importarla, he puesto en el build.gradle de nivel de proyecto esto: `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`. Y, en el de app, he puesto: `implementation 'com.github.Tupiet:TupiLibrary:1.0'`.

La librería está subida a GitHub ([aquí](https://github.com/Tupiet/TupiLibrary)), y he usado JitPack para poder usarla en los proyectos necesarios.

Todo pinta bien, y cuando estoy en el código de la app donde deseo poner la librería, puedo poner `TupiLibrary`, el "autoSuggest" me lo detecta, e incluso me pone el `import com.aleix.tupi_library.TupiLibrary`. El problema es cuando intento hacer `TupiLibrary.hello()`, pues el `.hello()` no lo detecta.

¿Hay alguna forma de solucionar eso? ¿Hay algo que haga mal? El código de la librería está [aquí](https://github.com/Tupiet/TupiLibrary), y la clase TupiLibrary se encuentra exactamente [aquí](https://github.com/Tupiet/TupiLibrary/blob/master/tupi_library/src/main/java/com/aleix/tupi_library/TupiLibrary.kt).

No sé qué más hacer para conseguirlo. He visto muchísimos vídeos, pero sigo igual. Así que, toda ayuda es bienvenida.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a la definiciòn de la funciòn  en la biblioteca:

```
package com.aleix.tupi_library

class TupiLibrary {

    fun hello(first: Int, second: Int): Int {

        val result = first + second
        return result
    }
}
```

Para llamar  la funciòn `hello()` debes instanciar la clase y posteriormente puedes hacer uso de la funciòn:

```
val tupiLibrary = TupiLibrary()
val resultado = tupiLibrary.hello(2,10)
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Esto solucionó completamente mi problema. Aún así, en ninguno de los tutoriales que vi se instancia esa clase... ¿Es porque usan Java? Por segunda vez, muchísimas gracias. ^^